# How to count the number of cells which contain specific text using Google Sheet Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

How to count the number of cells which contain specific text using Google sheet scripts?

Currently I'am using the following script to count the number of cells which contain specific text, for example cells which contain: 'Complete' or 'Not Complete'.

```
function COUNT_TEXT_ACROSS_SHEETS(sheetNames, range, text) {
  sheetNames = sheetNames.split(',');
  var count = 0;
  sheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var values = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
    values.forEach(function(row) {
      row.forEach(function(cell) {
        if (cell.indexOf(text) !== -1 ) count++;
      });
    });
  });
  return count;
};
```

**Currently the script counts both cells which contain the text 'Complete' and 'Not Complete'** is there a way to modify the script to only count cells which contain the full word 'Complete' instead of also counting cells which contain 'Not Complete' because the cell also contains the keyword: 'Complete'?

Example usage of the current script:

```
=COUNT_TEXT_ACROSS_SHEETS("Sheet1", "C1:C1000", "NOT COMPLETE")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder.html#findAll()) class.

#### Sample script:

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 * @return count of given text in spreadsheet
 * @param {string} text text to search
 * @param {boolean} mec whether to match entire cell
 * @param {boolean} mc whether to match case
 */
function COUNT_SS(text = 'NOT COMPLETE', mec = true, mc = true) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder(text)
    .matchEntireCell(mec)
    .matchCase(mc)
    .findAll()
    .length;
}
```

#### Usage:

```
=COUNT_SS()
```

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function COUNT_TEXT_ACROSS_SHEETS(sheetNames, range, text) {//text=['Complete','Not Complete']
  var nA=sheetNames.split(',');
  var tA=text.split(',');
  var count = 0;
  var cObj={};
  cObj[tA[0]]=0;
  cObj[tA[1]]=0;
  nA.forEach(function(name) {
    var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name);
    var vA = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
    vA.forEach(function(r) {
      r.forEach(function(c) {
        var idx0=c.indexOf(tA[0]);
        var idx1=c.indexOf(tA[1]);
        if(idx0!=-1 && idx1==-1)cObj[tA[0]]+=1;
        if(idx0!=-1 && idx1!=-1)cObj[tA[1]]+=1  
      });
    });
  });
  return Utilities.formatString('Count-%s:%s Count-%s:%s',tA[0],cObj[tA[0]],tA[1],cObj[tA[1]]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I just went ahead and added this for now. `cObj[tA[0]]=0;cObj[tA[1]]=0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C1:C1000;"=NOT COMPLETE")
```

Comment: Hi @user59892 thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Range should not be quoted.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.